# how to include an arrayed @if in laravel

Tags: php, angular, laravel, laravel-4

I'm still a newbie in Laravel, I'm using Laravel 4.2
Is there a way where if the author_ID is matched with Auth::ID it will show the specific line of codes

Code blade example:

```
@if ($data['authorID'] == Auth::id())
    <a href="@{{invoice_url}}" target="_blank">
            @{{payment_date | date:_dateFormat.shortDate}}
    </a>
@else
    <p>@{{payment_date | date:_dateFormat.shortDate}}</p>
@endif
```

Where author_id's data is this

```
$data['authorID'] = [
                     author_id => 5,
                     author_id => 2
                     ]
```

Comment: Unrelated: since you're new to Laravel, any specific reason why chose you start with Laravel4.2? That's a veeery old version

Comment: @brombeer the system framework has been using Laravel4.2 for quite a long time

Comment: Look at `in_array()` - see [PHP's in_array() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). You cannot compare a value with an array directly.

Comment: An array cannot have multiple `author_id` indices. What is `$data` and how was it generated? It's not usual to use arrays in a view, normal one works with collections of Eloquent models.

Comment: @miken32 $data is a bunch of arrays returned into a single variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution instead of using @if I've used ng-if to get the result I want

```
<a href="@{{trx.invoice_url}}" target="_blank" ng-if= "auth_id == trx.author_id || role">
        @{{trx.payment_date | date:_dateFormat.shortDate}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@if (in_array(Auth::id(),$data['authorID']))
    <a href="@{{invoice_url}}" target="_blank">
            @{{payment_date | date:_dateFormat.shortDate}}
    </a>
@else
    <p>@{{payment_date | date:_dateFormat.shortDate}}</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

`you should use in_array like this example`
`$people = array("Peter","Joe","Glenn","Cleveland");`

`if (in_array("Glenn", $people))`

`{ echo "Match found"; }`
`else{ echo "Match not found"; }`